# What happens when result of new Class() is not assigned to a variable

Tags: java, class, reference

I came across this code that says

```
new Class_Name();    // (i)
```

Now, normally I see the result of the new statement assigned to a variable:

```
Class_Name n = new Class_Name();
```

And `n` reference to the object created. What really happens when the (i) is called? And why would anyone want to do it? What are the uses for it?

CODE

```
class Tree {
  int height;
  Tree() {
    print("Planting a seedling");
    height = 0;
  }

  Tree(int initialHeight) {
    height = initialHeight;
    print("Creating new Tree that is " +
    height + " feet tall");
  }

  void info() {
    print("Tree is " + height + " feet tall");
  }
  void info(String s) {
    print(s + ": Tree is " + height + " feet tall");
  }
}
enter code here
public class Overloading {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  Tree t = new Tree(i);
  t.info();
  t.info("overloaded method");
  }
// Overloaded constructor:
new Tree();
}
}
```

Comment: *"why would anyone want to do it?"*   That depends on what is in the constructor for `Class_Name()`. For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: no offense but after 3 years on SO you should really know how to format your posts

Comment: @MarcoForberg Sorry, I just copied the formatted code and expected it to be formatted here too. Did the edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*What really happens when the (i) is called*

The below line of code creates an object of type `Class_Name` and since it is not referred by any reference variable , it dies immediately.

```
new Class_Name();
```

This way you can create an object of that class , and invoke methods on it without assigning it to a reference. This you will do when you need that object only once in your code and don't want to unnecessarily keep a reference to it . The anonymous object is created and dies instantaneously. This is quick and dirty :

```
new Class_Name().someMethod();
```

In I/O streams and AWT, we use many objects only once in the program; for them, better go for anonymous objects as follows.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

**After the Edit:**

```
new Tree();
```

Your intention here was to execute the code in the constructor .But your code won't compile I believe you need to put the last line inside some method.

Comment: `new Class_Name().someMethod();`  If the OP's code  did that, it would be a reasonable explanation.  The OP's code *doesn't* do that.

Answer (score 2):

```
new Class_Name();
```

This statement will create the object of `Class_Name` and constructor will be called but you are not holding the refernece of that class, so you can not call any other method. Here this Object scope will be limited where it has written, say in method or block.

A general use of it. `new Thread(new RunnableTest()).start();`

```
class RunnableTest implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
       for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
          System.out.println("i : "+i);
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you want to use oop you must create lots of class with a lots of attribute

and sometimes you need to use a attribute of some class in a specific class so you need to

create a object of those class by using

```
new Class_Name();
```

Answer (score 0):

`new class_name()` will create object of `class_name`.As you are not storing reference of it ,you will not be able to use same object in the code after this statement.But it's good practice to store the reference of object if you want to use it later in code.Which will help you to reduce efforts in managing multiple objects and memory too.